# Windows 10 wants 10 GB disk space for current updates, is this OK?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

On my working computer, I am regularly keeping ~12 GB free on my single 256 GB SSD disk and it's enough. But right now Windows 10 Update is saying it needs at least 10 GB for the updates. That's ridiculous large amount, it never needed so much up to now! Is that normal, is that OK? Or is it some error?

[image]

(Some messages in Czech unfortunatelly)

[image]

Comment: You’re trying to install a big update (21H2). // 12 GiB is not enough breathing room. You also want space for system restore points and whatnot.

Comment: @DanielB how do you know? I googled 21H2 and it says it was out already on November 2021, and this comupter was updated many times since then. Or is that the only update which was so big?

Comment: @Tomas - You are absolutely attempting to install 21H2, and you are NOT running the current version of Windows 10, because your first screenshot indicates it's attempting to download Windows 10 21H2.  The upgrade as likely been failing for months due to space issues.

Comment: 12GB is simply not enough free space on any drive. You must keep 10-15% free even on a large drive. Ironically this %age has to increase for a small drive. I'd be aiming to always have 30-40GB free on such a small drive. An SSD will rapidly fail if kept too full, as it's having to constantly re-use the same few sectors.

Answer (score 4):

> Windows 10 wants 10 GB disk space for current updates, is this OK?

Yes.

This is a feature update, and the update will create Windows.old so that you may roll back if you wish to.

Windows.old can range from 15 to 30 GB depending on what Windows.old needs to save.

So the amount is entirely normal.

You may wish to back up big documents to an external drive temporarily.

Then update, then ensure you are happy, then use Disk Cleanup to delete Windows.old (it will go away in a month) and restore the documents you backed off.

This will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft article
[Quick fixes - Verify disk space](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/quick-fixes#verify-disk-space)
says this:

> At least 16 GB of free space must be available on the system drive to upgrade a 32-bit OS, or 20 GB for a 64-bit OS.

This article is not the latest, and Windows has been getting larger,
so a bit more than 20GB might be required now.
But it's clear that your 12GB are far from being enough.

Comment: And, those figures (16 GB, 20 GB) are general figures for any updates? Or is that about  one particular update?

Comment: They are general, but better take them as the absolute minimum. You would be safer with a few more GBs added in.